# I have problems returning an object from parent ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I have 4 classes ( I will shorten them for convenience).

```
public class PoliceStation{
public String name;
 ArrayList<Owner> owners = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean addOwner(Owner owner) {
        if(findOwnerID(owner)) {
            this.owners.add(owner);
            System.out.println("Owner "+owner.getName()+" added.");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Owner "+owner.getName()+" with "+owner.getOwnerIDNumber()+" not added.");
        return false;
    }
```

and a few more classes for finding owner objects.

And `Owner` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Owner {
    String name;
    String dateOfBirth;
    long ownerIDNumber;
    String address;
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    ArrayList<Fine> penalties = new ArrayList<Fine>();
public Vehicle findVehicleObject(String plateNum) {
    for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if(vehicles.get(i).getPlateNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(plateNum)) {
            System.out.println("Vehicle with that plate number "+plateNum+" exists.");
            return vehicles.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Vehicle doesnt exist with "+plateNum);
    return null;
}
```

Which consists of addVehicle methods, findVehicle etc.

Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle extends Owner{
    PoliceStation ps = new PoliceStation("center");

    String plateNumber;
    String name;
    String type;
    //String serialNum;

    public Vehicle(String driverName, String dateOfBirth,long ownerID, String address,String plateNumber, String name, String type) {
        super(driverName,dateOfBirth,ownerID,address);
        this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

With findVehicle method that should return the vehicle object with the vehicle's plate number:

```
public Vehicle findVehicle1(String plateNum) {
    if(this.plateNumber==plateNum) {
        System.out.println("Lookin "+plateNum);
        return super.findVehicleObject(plateNum);
    }else return null;
}
```

And after that I have a fourth class called `RadioCam` that reads a `plateNumber` from a car: (note: the following code is badly written because I've been trying to get this to work without success)

```
class RadioCam{
public void detection(double speed) {
    System.out.println("Vehicle detected.");
    //speed would be a variable that the radioCam would return using radiowaves and doppler effect
    if(speed>50) {
        String plateNumber = takePicture();
        Vehicle veh = new Vehicle(plateNumber);
        veh = veh.findVehicle1(plateNumber);//<-- null
        System.out.println("-------------------"+veh.getName());//<- null here as well
        Owner ownerFine = ps.getOwner(veh);
        ownerFine= ps.getOwner(veh);
        System.out.println("sssssss"+ownerFine.getName());
        //ownerFine = PoliceStation.getOwner(veh);
        ps.addFine(ownerFine, "speed violation", veh);//<- so this method doesnt work in the end becuse ownerFine and veh are null
```

Which returns null to `veh = veh.findVehicle1(plateNumber);`. And going back to Owner class at `public Vehicle findVehicleObject(String plateNum) {
    for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++) {` <-- vehicle.size() is 0 so it doesn't go through the vehicles at all. 
I get it that I need an owner object from the arraylist to get to the vehicle object from the arraylist, but in this case I need a vehicle object from plateNumber (which is a part of the Vehicle class) and from the vehicle object to get the owner object that owns the vehicle object.

I hope I explained my problems good enough.

Comment: So? You simply need a method `findVehicle` in `PoliceStation` which iterates over all the owners and asks each owner if he owns a vehicle with the given number.

Comment: @luk2302 I forgot about that completely. I just tried it, it still gave me that owners.size() is 0 unless I declare it static, then it works

Answer (score 0):

Try equals method to compare values, `this.plateNumber==plateNum` may be false even they have same value.

```
public Vehicle findVehicle1(String plateNum) {
    if(this.plateNumber.equals(plateNum)) {
        System.out.println("Lookin "+plateNum);
        return super.findVehicleObject(plateNum);
    }else return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `findVehicle1(String plateNum)` method you are comparing two strings with the `==` operator, while you should be using [string.equals(Object other)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Try changing

```
 if(this.plateNumber==plateNum) {
```

to

```
 if(this.plateNumber.equals(plateNum)) {
```

Also when constructing your vehicle object, you're ommiting a lot of the needed parameters

```
public Vehicle(String driverName, String dateOfBirth,long ownerID, String address,String plateNumber, String name, String type) {
```

^ the constructor asks for 7 parameters, while you only give

```
new Vehicle(plateNumber);
```

one parameter. Therefore of course your `veh.getName()` method will return null, because it's an attribute that you did not maintain when you created your vehicle object.

After fixing those issues, you can think about your general code structure, like where to implement loops and such.

I don't know whether or not you use an IDE, but if you do please familiarize yourself with the the debugging functionality to follow the code execution step-by-step in called methods. You could have easily pinpointed the lines of code that act in ways they shouldn't act (after all you already found the lines where null is the result of your method calls).

Comment: I know that its a bit messed up. I was just testing something and forgot to clean it up before posting it here. The problem is that it was giving me that the owners arraylist was empty, so it was giving me null. luk2302 gave me the answer. I had to put the findVehicle method in the PoliceStation class